# How can I check the two checkboxes on Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNSwW.png) <- I have a google sheet like in the photo. When I check the box behind the cars here, the name of that car is written in the result section. I want that when I tick one of the two checkboxes, the other will not be checked. That is, only one of the two checkboxes should be selected at a time. When one is selected, the other should not be selected. How can I solve this with google sheets formulas without writing app script code?

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEsV1.png) <- The formula in cell D2:

`=IFS(COUNTIF(A2, TRUE),B2,COUNTIF(A3, TRUE),B3,COUNTIF(A2, False),"",COUNTIF(A3, False),"")`

Comment: Hi @Alim, I have posted an alternative answer to your question below. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: Hello, I have reviewed your alternative suggestion. Unfortunately it's not what I wanted. I want the checkbox to act like the ratio button. It is a pity that this cannot be done in Google sheet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One checked checkbox at a time (similar to a radio button behavior) isn't actually supported in Google Sheets at the moment.

However, there are certain ways to circumvent this kind of issue. It can be via `Apps Script` or `Sheets` itself.

Since you are looking for a `Sheets` related solution, an alternative would be using an in-cell dropdown instead of checkboxes. That way, you could only select just one car at a time and you don't need complex formula to get the chosen value itself, you just need to set the cell formula to `=B2` to get the dropdown chosen value.

#### Sample:

[image: output]

To add a dropdown in `Sheets`, see the reference below:

#### Reference:

- [Drop-down List](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)